# Reliability of a cheap SSD and Data loss

Tags: ssd

I have seen many cheap USB sticks die while good ones never(for me). Does this imply on SSDs too? I mean do cheap SSDs are vulnerable to die in normal usage?

Comment: Today's Solid State Drives (SSDs) are working better than the older technology's SSDs. They are much more reliable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's more of a question of technology they use.

> In the real world, MLC-based designs – believed less reliable than SLC designs – are often as reliable as SLC. (The findings state that "SLC [is] not generally more reliable than MLC".) But generally it is said, that the Write endurance is the following:
>
> SLC NAND: 100,000 erases per block
>
> MLC NAND: 5,000 to 10,000 erases per block for medium-capacity applications, and 1,000 to 3,000 for high-capacity applications
>
> TLC NAND: 1,000 erases per block

I believe JEDEC publish metrics on drive reliability. Definitely worth a Google.

Comment: And we already have QLC NAND. Wikipedia says PLC is in the works.